# Cycle through divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<div id="container">

<div class="boxes">first box</div>
<div class="boxes">second box</div>
<div class="boxes">third box</div>

</div>

<a href="jquery">Show me next box</a>
```

Consider that initially only the first box is visible. When I click 'Show me next box' I want the current visible box to be hidden, and the next `.boxes` on the list to appear.

The only thing that I think it gets close is the `.each` function, but I shouldn't cycle through all `div`s just to show one, I think.

Comment: Take a look through the bazillion related questions.

Comment: @tomalak i searched before ask this but i didn't find any related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var visibleBox = $('#container .boxes:visible');
    visibleBox.hide();
    var nextToShow = $(visibleBox).next('.boxes:hidden');
    if (nextToShow.length > 0) {
        nextToShow.show();
    } else {
        $('#container .boxes:hidden:first').show();
    }
    return false;
});
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d6nZP/1/).

Comment: @Darin: Very nice. It doesn't actually cycle, though.

Comment: `:visible` applies for `display:none`? Ops seeing your live demo the answer is it works

Comment: @yes123, if an element has `display:none` style applied then `:visible` won't select it.

Comment: darin i edited (the var is useless). I will accept this anyway

Comment: Huston we have a problem. This will not start form the beginning when the last box showes :/ It will just hidden the last box

Comment: darin see my last comment pls. This is a HUGE problem for me :(

Comment: Maybe before running that command we should check if the .boxes:visible is the last div of the #container and do something according

Comment: @yes123, answer and live demo updated to take this into account.

Comment: accepted.. length did the trick. I think jQuery should have gave another name to length method because as is it's a bit misleading

Comment: @darin: Darin do you know why if I add dynamically another div with class .boxes it doesn't get cycled tru?

Comment: @yes123, how, where, when are you adding this new div? Could you provide a http://jsfiddle.net example illustrating the problem?

Comment: there ya go: http://jsfiddle.net/EHEQ8/ as you can see i add the class to that box as first line of code.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function(){
    $('.boxes').filter(':visible').hide().next().add('.boxes:first').last().show();
});
```

Comment: I love the way you chained the stuff. Also, shouldn't it be `.first` instead of `.last`?

Comment: You'd think so, wouldn't you?  No, it's supposed to be `.last` since for some reason the elements always come out in _first-in-document_ order.

Comment: haha, you're right. I remember reading in the release notes of a recent version :)

Comment: yep, here it is http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2#Elements_Returned_in_Document_Order