# Rotating coverflow effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML:

```
- for (x in dict)
  div.test
    div.ContentFlow
      div.loadIndicator
        div.indicator
      div.flow
        - for (var i in dict[x])
          img(class='item', src='/images/' + dict[x][i] + '.jpg')
```

my CSS:

```
.test {
  display:block;
}
.ContentFlow {
  margin-top: 10%;
}
```

client-side JS:

```
var count = 0
var items;
var amount = 0;
$(window).load(function(){
    items = $("#test .ContentFlow");
    amount = items.length;

    items.hide();
    items.eq(count).show();
}
$(window).load(setInterval(function(){

    // tried this as well
    //var items = $("#test .ContentFlow");
    //var amount = items.length;

    items.eq(count).hide();
    count >= amount-1 ? count = 0 : count++;
    items.eq(count).show();

}, 1000));
```

ConentFlow css/js:
http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/docu.php

I am trying to rotate the .ContentFlow div every 5 secs. However, its not working. After setting display:none for ContentFlow class, nothing gets displayed at load time and thereafter. If I dont set display:none for ContentFlow divs in my css, all the divs show up at load time

Which properties should I use for it to work. Please let me know if the question is not clear.

Comment: This looks like a javascript question, seeing as you're trying to have it change over time.

Comment: No. Thats not what I want. Just imagine I have 5 ContentFlows with 10 images. And I want to rotate those 5 ContentFlows every 3 secs. Each ContentFlow has it own div. To make sure, I do not want a ContentFlow containing other ContentFlow(s).

Comment: I just checked at the [**ContentFlow website**](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) and the latest version supports multiple ContentFlow's on the same webpage. Will delete some previous messages and cleanup a bit.

Comment: This [SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6003060/1195891) shows how to cycle div's if that is what you need. Also, there's another jsFiddle shown at the end of that Answers comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move

```
items = $(".ContentFlow");
var amount = items.length;
```

inside the functions so that it is executed after window load.

---

Refactored:

```
var count = 0;

$(window).load(function(){

    // Hide at first
    $("#test .ContentFlow").hide();

    // Start repeating toggle
    setInterval(function(){

        var items = $("#test .ContentFlow");
        var amount = items.length;

        items.eq(count).hide();
        (count >= amount-1) ? count = 0 : count++;
        items.eq(count).show();

    }, 1000);
};
```

Instead of doing the initial hiding using `$("#test .ContentFlow").hide();`, you might want to just set a style `.ContentFlow{display:none;}` to avoid flicker when the page is still loading.

Comment: actually the purpose of moving it inside was that the problem is probably that the code is executed before the browser has loaded the `.ContentFlow` elements.

Comment: Guys...I think this was the problem. If I load all elements first and then start hiding them one by one, after that cycling/rotation happens correctly. But moving the above code inside $(window).load() does not work properly. So, how do I make sure all the elements are loaded but are shown only as I need it? I cleaned up code/comments

Comment: "Does not work properly" in my comment above means not all the ContentFlow divs have all its content. Some have partial content. Sometimes all the ContentFlow divs have all their content. I think somehow, as mentioned, code is being executed before all the elements from CF are loaded.

Comment: Actually I don't see why the divs wouldn't load properly all the time. The only thing I would expect to be sketchy is which ones are shown/hidden. Note though that the code above should be inside *both* functions. Also, the way you're calling setInterval() and passing the result to load() seems a bit off, though I think it should work. But the cleanest would be to just put the setInterval call inside the first load() callback, after the initialization code.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you use the latest version of [**ContentFlow v1.0.2**](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/index.php) that allows for multiple ContentFlows to be on the same webpage, each with a unique JavaScript handler.

Then, you can use the [**ContentFlow Slideshow Plugin**](http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/addons.php#ContentFlow_slideshow) which you then handle all the timing requirements you need.

The nice thing about the Slideshow plugin is that each ContentFlow can be set to a different timing speed.

Comment: I didn't post any code snippets since the usage markup is at that website (access the links in my answer). After giving a name to each ContentFlow player, the separately loaded Slideshow Plugin has only a few lines of options to set for each one... really straightforward for a fierce script.

Comment: @gaurav jain, place your `items=` and `var amount=` inside a jQuery Document Ready function. Also, you need to have a jsFiddle/test link so one can troubleshoot what's really going on. Side note: Don't provide global status reports as comments in posts... add that to your own comments or answer section as a update.