# jQuery fadeToggle one after the other

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function the toggles two divs with fadeToggle.

```
 $(".container .readmore").click(function() {
            $(".container .content-teaser").fadeToggle('slow');
            $(".container .content-full").fadeToggle('slow');
        });
```

But I need it to fade the visible one out THEN fade the hidden one in. then vise versa.

Any ideas?

Thanks
C

UPDATE: please check jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tSmUA/4/

Now I have an issue when toggleing back it shows both divs for a moment.

Comment: Use a process that handles unlimited amount of divs to be cycled: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6003126/1536309

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple fix.  At the end of the Fade function use the second parameter of fadeToggle to provide a callback once the animation is complete.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/

Below will do the fade, and then once that fade is complete the anonymous function  is invoked.  To do the fading in reverse just modify the selectors appropriately.

```
$(".container .readmore").click(function() {
            $(".container .content-teaser").fadeToggle('slow', function ()
                {
                   $(".container .content-full").fadeToggle('slow');
                });          
        });
```

**UPDATE:** 
Questioner had issues getting the fading to work in reverse. Updated code to show how to do the fading in reverse.

```
$(".container .readmore").click(function() {
    var container = $(".container");  //Narrow the selector to the container
    var teaser = $(".content-teaser", container);
    var fullContent = $(".content-full", container);

    //Check to see if the teaser is visible
    if(teaser.is(':visible'))
    {
        teaser.fadeToggle('slow', function ()
                           {
                               fullContent.fadeToggle('slow');
                           });      
    }
    else
    {
        fullContent.fadeToggle('slow', function ()
                            {
                               teaser.fadeToggle('slow');
                            });      
    }
});
```

Sample can be viewed at: http://jsfiddle.net/v25zx/

**Update 2:**
Added another revision to the fading code. This simplifies the jquery animations:

http://jsfiddle.net/sGpj6/

Comment: When I press the readmore to toggle back I get both divs shows for a brief moment.

Comment: Could you provide an example on jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: I don't see both divs looks fine to me

Comment: so when you hit read more for the second time you don't see the `content-teaser` fade in then `content-full` fade out after it?

Comment: Thats what I ment when I said "To do the fading in reverse just modify the selectors appropriately."  I updated the answer to show you how to do that as well.

Comment: Sorry, totaly missunderstood that, Thanks so much for the update.

Comment: Could you checkout my second update, and then accept the answer?