# jQuery fadeIn / fadeOut instead of fadeToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to fade out an image and fade in another which has `display` set to `none`. I can do it using `fadeToggle` but I would like to add a delay to avoid having the second image display before the first one finishes fading out.

Found this question here that kind of gives me the answer:
[jQuery fadeToggle one after the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290468/jquery-fadetoggle-one-after-the-other)

This answer uses different classes but I would like to use the class of the parent element to the images to fade out the first child and fade in the second child. Then once it's clicked again reverse all.

I have the first part working which fades out image 1 and then fades in image 2 after a delay. But when I click again, image 2 fades out and fades back in.

Here my html:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="target">
        <div class="visOn"><img src="http://placehold.it/300x300" alt=""></div>
        <div class="visOff"><img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt=""></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
    .visOff{
    display:none;
```

Here's the JS:

```
    $('.target').click(function(){

        var icon1 = $(this).children();
        var icon2 = $(this).children().eq(1);

        if (icon1.is(':visible')){
            icon1.fadeOut('slow');
            icon2.delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
        }
        else if (icon2.is(':visible')){
            icon2.fadeOut('slow');
            icon1.delay(500).fadeIn('slow');
        }
    });
```

Here's a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/asantoni/ex30v3rh/

Comment: This is straight forward, here -> **https://jsfiddle.net/ex30v3rh/3/**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to solve with a simple CSS

https://jsfiddle.net/ex30v3rh/1/

```
.target {
    position: relative;
}
.target > div {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: @marcosperes Thanks a lot!

Comment: @marcosperes The css you added is to keep the second image in the same place as the first one, right?

Comment: @Marcos, very nice solution.

Comment: And you can control it with top, bottom, right and left ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a different approach,

I've updated the JSFiddle, this does not toggle, but works with classes, the benefit is that this also gives you more control on the behavior of the elements.

```
var switchFade = function(){
    e_on = $('.visOn');
    e_off = $('.visOff');

    $(e_on).animate({'opacity':0},'slow',function(){
        $(e_on).removeClass('visOn').addClass('visOff');
        $(e_off).addClass('visOn').removeClass('visOff');
        $(e_off).css({'opacity':0});
        $(e_off).animate({'opacity':1},'slow');
    });
};  


$('.target').click(function(){
    switchFade();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ex30v3rh/5/